# how to compress 2GB files using TAR in python

Tags: python, tar, tarfile

I need to create a single file archive containing several 5 * 2-3GB files and several smaller ones.

As far as I understand, tgz doesn't support multithreading, and the process takes about 30-40 mins, using a single core of the server to its maximum.

Is there a way to expedite it?

```py
tar = tarfile.open("./my.tar.gz", "w:gz")
for _ in [list, of, files]:
    tar.add(_, _.name)
tar.close()
```